# What kind of objects are this in Java?

Tags: java, object

I am trying to learn Java and I'm getting to the point where I am creating objects.

For example, if I have a class named `Test`:

```
Test newTest = new Test();
```

I get that I created an object. But what I don't understand is when the `new Test();` is different, like this:

```
Test newTest = getTest();
```

What does this exactly mean?

Comment: please provide the code of the Test class, so that it will be easier for us to explain. The new Test() calls the constructor of Test that creates a new Test instance, while getTest() calls an accessor method, that returns an instance of Test. That is just an assumption, until you post the code

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 1):

The first is initialization.

While the second is a method that returns Test type object

Answer (score 1):

I guess, `getTest()` is a method, which returns reference to a `Test` object, and you are assigning that returned object to variable `newTest`.

Your `getTest()` method may be like following

```
public Test getTest()   {
   return new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`new Test()` creates a new instance (object) of class `Test`.

`getTest()` is a method that returns a reference to an instance of class `Test` or a sub-class of `Test` (assuming that this code compiles without errors).

`getTest()` may have internally called `new Test()` to create the returned instance, or it may have obtained it by some other means (for example, the class that contains the `getTest()` method may have a `setTest(Test test)` method that stores a reference to an instance of `Test`, which later can be accessed by a call to `getTest()`).